# No sound after installation of Windows drivers (Boot Camp) Windows 8.1

Tags: mac, windows, usb

I got Windows installed to my MacBook. The only problem is, that I was not having any sound even though the drivers were installed. I was told that using Boot Camp to create the USB boot causes that, and that I should use the Windows USB Creation tool.

I did that today, and I've created a partition on Disk Utility, plugged in the USB stick and it's recognised on my OS X desktop. I checked on Disk Utility, and it's there too. I restarted the computer and presssed <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> to open Startup Manager, and the USB drive doesn't even show up.

I installed rEFIt and that did not help. I noticed that it says on Disk Utility that the USB is no longer SMART supported, so could that be a factor? Eventually I'll just have to give in and install Windows via Boot Camp and no longer have sound.

---

Macbook Pro 2011 13" (Early) - 10.9.5 (Wiped all my drives using a command in Command Prompt on Windows not realising I'd remove my OS X so that's why I am down graded.)

Comment: rEFIt is outdated. If you are using yosemite, use rEFInd. They said that yosemite had them to tweak it to work.

Comment: I have posted a full tutorial on how to properly make a bootable USB and how o install rEFInd with the expectation, that you are using yosemite (Works on mavericks too though)

Comment: Do you guys know how I can fix the sound, also?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this method to make a bootable disk. Make sure to backup the USB and format as FAT32.

### Creating a bootable USB manually:

First unplug USB and run:

```
diskutil list
```

Take note of the output. Then plug in your usb and run `diskutil list` again. You will see that there is one more disk. Of you have only your HD and the usb, it should be `/dev/disk1` for you. The command is there to check.

[image]

This is an example of an output. The way you know it is your usb, is that in one of the lines, there will be the name. So Recovery HD and Macintosh HD is the main hard drive. And `/dev/disk2` is a USB (Note: This is an example from the Internet, so It might not be a USB. It is just to show you the way it works)

Once you defined your USB /dev/disknumber, take note of the path to your iso. Mine would be: `/Users/myusername/Desktop/Windows.iso`

Then you run this (**Again, make sure you formatted to FAT and backed up!**)

```
sudo dd if=/Users/yourusername/Desktop/Windows.iso of=/dev/disk2 bs=1m
```

- Remember to replace yourusername with your username and proper path, and sisk2 with the number of your disk.
- If you get an error with bs, replace 1m with 1M

### Installing rEFInd (If you cannot see the USB)

Get rEFInd [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/). Once you download, open terminal and `cd /path/to/refind` Then just enter `./install.sh` It will show that you should edit a config file located in `/efi/refind.conf` (note: Check if this path is corect. I cannot check now because I am on iPad.) edit with `sudo open -e /efi/refind.conf` There are comments which will tell you how to edit it.

Comment: Thanks for the help but do you know how I can get the sound working also?

Comment: @BenDent If you correctly install Windows, sound should work properly. If not, you might need some additional kernel drivers which I can research about. Windows Support and a properly installed Windows on a partition, It almost certainly will work...